# CSS sticky footer - problems with content styling

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to implement a sticky footer with CSS. I realize that this is a common problem and so I tried the various solutions found via Google.

However, none of the solutions I found accomplished quite what I'm trying to do. I not only want the footer to be at the bottom, but also that I can put a `div` between the header and the footer which takes up all the available space, even when there is not enough content (Imagine if you put a border around `#content`, it should expand from the header all the way down to footer, no matter how much content there is.).

This is where the solutions fail. Either a "push" element gets in the way. Or, there is no way to set that `div` to 100% without destroying the footer or increasing the page width beyond 100%.

Here's the basic markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <header>
            Header!
        </header>
        <div id="content">
            Content!
        </div>
        <footer>
            Footer!
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Once again, I have run out of ideas to make CSS do what I want it to do. I may not use Javascript. Help?

EDIT: I would prefer the header to have a dynamic height. The footer should not be visible at all times. It should work like [this](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com).

EDIT 2: It should look kind of like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/awTZS/), except that the black area should extend all the way to the footer.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make the "content" 100% height, you must set `html` and `body` both to `100%` height and the `min-height` of the content to `100%` as well.

You also need padding on the top/bottom of the content so that the header and footer (absolutely positioned so as not to mess with the 100% height to create an unnecessary scrollbar).  This padding requires that you know the height of header/footer, but since they are supposed to be static it's highly probable that you do.

Finally, `border-box` is needed as the `box-sizing` of the content to prevent the padding from *adding* to the height.

This works regardless of the size of content.

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
#content {
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: white;
}
header {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: yellow;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
footer {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: red;
    height: 50px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

In action:

http://jsfiddle.net/s8gZB/2/

http://jsfiddle.net/s8gZB/1/

Comment: I made an edit to my question, the footer should not be visible at all  times, it should work like [this](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com).

Comment: @ryyst so more like this? http://jsfiddle.net/s8gZB/3/ (uncomment JS and run again to increase size of `#content`

Comment: Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/awTZS/), except that the black part should extend all the way to footer.

Comment: The black part in your fiddle extends beneath the footer, too (as revealed by removing the red background color from the footer). The black part in my fiddle shouldn't do this, instead it should "stop" before the footer, and there should be a blue margin around it.

Comment: @ryyst why does it make a difference if the footer obscures it anyway?

Comment: Because (for aesthetic reasons) there should be a border around the inner content. If the lower part of the inner content is obscured by the footer, so will the border and the design will look messed up.

Comment: Just increase the border size on the top and bottom to compensate for the overflow: http://jsfiddle.net/s8gZB/5/

Comment: @ryyst it should be *me* that never ceases to amaze you

Comment: You never do, oh mighty master! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this for footer

position: fixed;

bottom:0 ;

Footer will always be visible, No matter where the scroll is.

Comment: I'm sorry if I was unclear, but the footer should not always be visible.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to have an absolute `div` for your content on which you set both `top: HEADER_HEIGHT;` and `bottom: FOOTER_HEIGHT;`

Also to push the div `inner` to have height of 100%, its parent should have a `height` not `min-height`.  To prevent problems from changing `min-height` to `height`, you should add `overflow: visible;`.

Comment: Is it possible with a dynamic header height?

Comment: You can put the header in this div too and set 0 on top.

Comment: I don't see a difference to [this](http://jsfiddle.net/awTZS/). The black part should extend all the way to the footer. It looks good if the content is large enough.

Comment: If something like background is important, you can put it on `#container`. Anyhow, I'm trying to do it with `#inner`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/GEbsq/2/ Here it is. I've just changed `min-height` to `height` and added `overflow: visible;` This works the same but enables us to use `height: 100%;` for the child.